# How do I set git up to keep my files in sync?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, git-remote, git-checkout

I'm having a problem with getting my Git repository to function the way that I want it to. I'm sure it can do what I want, but I'm just not figuring it out on my own. Here's my setup...

- PC1: This is my dev machine where I created the repository, and make changes to it.
- SERVER1: This is where my remote Git repository is located, and all changes are pushed to it from PC1.
- PC2: This is my QA machine. I cloned the Git repo from SERVER1. I wish to checkout whatever branch I want to test from the remote repository, and be able to do pulls to get the latest code.

I use TortoiseGit on both PCs. I created a branch (2012_2_2) on PC1, committed changes, and pushed to SERVER1. From PC2, I selected "Switch/Checkout", and checked out remotes/orgin/2012_2_2.

Sadly, this doesn't work. When I look at the properties of the PC2 repository, the Current Branch say "fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic link". Also, I am unable to pull changes made to branch 2012_2_2. When I select pull from the menu, the only branch available to pull from is origin/master.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You are using TortoiseGit on the PC's so you maybe aren't knowing exactly what commands they are using.  But to push a branch initially to the server you would do `git push -u origin newbranch` if origin points to that remote.  Once the branch is there you would be able to pull all branches to PC2.  `git pull origin` should pull all branches down.  Then you should be able to `git checkout 2012_2_2`  It might be easier to use the command line tools to learn Git than a tool that hides the steps. You will be better off for it in the long run.

Comment: I'm wondering if when I check out the remote branch onto PC2, should I select the "create branch" option to have a local copy of the branch?

Comment: When you checkout the branch it should create it, as it would come down from the repository.  We can chat from my profile if you want to talk this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. There's a check box in Tortoise when you do the Switch/Checkout for creating a branch. I was unchecking that thinking that I didn't need to create the branch. Leaving it checked solved my problem.